# Formal non-CM in local fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, complex-multiplication, class-field-theory, formal-groups

An elliptic curve $E$ with complex multiplication by an imaginary quadratic field $F$ has $\ell$-adic Galois representations that essentially encode the class field theory of $F$ - in other words, the reciprocity in abelian extensions of $F$, or equivalently, in extensions generated by the division points of $E$. For me, "reciprocity" means a way of determining the splitting of primes in an extension.

As Shimura (c.f. *A Reciprocity Law in Non-Solvable Extensions*) and many others have shown, one can use modularity to deduce reciprocity laws in extensions generated by torsion points of non-CM elliptic curves.

In another direction, Lubin and Tate showed that the theory of complex multiplication can be constructed formally for $p$-adic fields in order to generate the class field theory of any $p$-adic field.

My question is: can one generalize Lubin and Tate to non-abelian extensions and get a formal analogue of the reciprocity laws given by non-CM elliptic curves?

Comment: I think this is exactly what people call "non-Abelian Lubin-Tate theory."

Comment: Dear Moosbrugger and Davidac, The direct analogue of passing from a CM elliptic curve to a non-CM elliptic curve would be passing from a Lubin--Tate formal group to some more general kind of formal group.    This is not what happens in non-abelian LT theory.  Rather, one looks at the moduli space of Lubin--Tate formal groups (and its congruence covers), and looks at its higher cohomology.  (The $H^0$ recovers Lubin--Tate formal CM theory.)   So this is more like using modular curves to construct non-abelian reciprocity laws than random elliptic curves.  (Note that Shimura's paper is also ...

Comment: ... about the modular elliptic curve $X_0(11)$.)  Apologies to Moosbrugger, who surely knows all this; Davidac, if you want to pursue this, you could look at Carayol's paper in the Ann Arbor volumes (available on Milne's web-page) and then follow up the more recent literature (Harris and Taylor's book is probably the most significant more recent contribution).  Regards,

Comment: Dear Emerton, is not reasonable to ask if the galois representation afforded by the Tate module of a specific Lubin-Tate formal group of height 2 appears in the cohomology of some moduli space with level? If it is, wouldn't this be a reasonable direct analogue?